# How to add the GPL license into a source file in Kdevelop

Tags: kdevelop

Is there a way to automatically insert the GPL license common header comment into each source file in a Kdevelop 5 project?

Comment: Before or after creating the file? When creating a file from template, you can choose a licence in the wizard.

Comment: Actually both, because started one project long time ago but I can't either found the license option in the wizard for new projects when select "standard >> Terminal >> c++ with Make"

Comment: It seems the "new project" wizard does not show this option, but the "new file from template" wizard does